# JQuery - submit page containing multiple forms

Tags: jquery

I have a java/jsp application using custom framework on the server side.  This particular page is the view shopping cart that has a list of the items in the cart. In the list i have a form for each item to update qty or remove the item. I am using the multiple forms so i don't have to do as much work on the server side to figure out which item needs to be updated if I were to submit the entire list in one form.  I give each form the unique id of the product and i also add the same id to an attribute on the action link that triggers the submit.  On the click of action link I need to set the hidden field pageAction so on the server side this corresponds to an actionEvent that runs code for any specific page action.  So if cartUpdate was hit that need to be set to pageAction.  The below code works but I am just not sure if there is any bad practice in this as i primary stick to server side code ;)  i was mostly questioning the line in the js code:

```
 js("input[rel=actionButton]").val(action);
```

I am not sure if i also need to do a check that is is coming from the proper form by id?
Or if there is just a way better way to do this on the JS side then what i am doing.  Any advice would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!-- QUANTITY AND MANAGEMENT -->
<td class="cartQty" align="left" valign="top">
    <form id="${item.product.boId}" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/store/viewcart.do" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="1" maxlength="3" class="cartQtyBox">  
        <input type="hidden" value="${item.product.boId}" name="productId">
        <input type="hidden" value="${item.productStyle.boId}" name="productStyleId">
        <input type="hidden" name="pageAction" rel="actionButton">
        <a id="buttonAction" rel="buttonAction" action="cartUpdate" pid="${item.product.boId}" href="#" class="updateCart">Update</a>
        <span>|</span>
        <a id="buttonAction" rel="buttonAction" action="cartRemove" pid="${item.product.boId}" href="#" class="removeItem">Remove</a>
    </form>
</td>
```

**JS**

```
js(document).ready(function() {
    js("a[rel=buttonAction]").click(function(event){
        var formId = js(this).attr('pid');
        var action = js(this).attr('action');
        js("input[rel=actionButton]").val(action);
        js("#"+formId).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is this same question asked daily and the answer is always the same?

Comment: What is the "always the same" answer then?  I said the code was working, i am looking for advice on the subject and in my searching I did not find an exact solution.

Comment: @Phillip if you think this is happening, you can flag as duplicate (or vote to close if you have sufficient rep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `JSP` but you can make some changes and I think that is a good practice. At first you should not use any custom attribute in an element without the `data-` prefix, this is the recommended way in `HTML5` spec, so where you are using, for example

```
<a id="buttonAction" rel="buttonAction" action="cartUpdate" pid="${item.product.boId}" href="#" class="updateCart">Update</a>
<a id="buttonAction" rel="buttonAction" action="cartRemove" pid="${item.product.boId}" href="#" class="removeItem">Remove</a>
```

In this case, you should use

```
<a data-action="cartUpdate" data-pid="${item.product.boId}" href="#" class="updateCart buttonAction">Update</a>
<a data-action="cartRemove" data-pid="${item.product.boId}" href="#" class="removeItem buttonAction">Remove</a>
```

Now, notice that I've removed `id` and `rel` from both inputs and modified `action` and `pid` with a `data-` prefix and also added a new class `buttonAction` in both elements. First of all an `id` should be unique, which means that two element can't have same `id` and in your case you are not using those `id`s either so they are unnecessary. Also you have

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageAction" rel="actionButton" />
```

You can use

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageAction" />
```

You are using

```
js("a[rel=buttonAction]").click(function(event){ // ... });
```

In this case, you should use

```
js(".buttonAction").click(function(event){ // ... });
```

Here, `.buttonAction` is the class name for both `a` elements and you can use same class name for more than one element to group them. The dot (`.`) used for class name.
In your click handler you have

```
var formId = js(this).attr('pid');
var action = js(this).attr('action');
js("input[rel=actionButton]").val(action);
js("#"+formId).submit();
```

In this case you need only

```
event.preventDefault();
var action = js(this).attr('data-action');
js(this).closest('form').find('input[name="pageAction"]').val(action);
js(this).closest('form').submit();
```

So full code should be

```
js(document).ready(function() {
    js(".buttonAction").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = js(this).attr('data-action');
        js(this).closest('form').find('input[name="pageAction"]').val(action);
        js(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to answer my question. I assume that var action = js(this).attr('action'); should be var action = js(this).attr('data-action'); ? I do not get a value unless i change that to data-action.

Comment: In addition if I try to remove the first item in the cart it will get a value for the pageAction, however when i try to remove the second item in the list it seems that data-action is blank and pageAction gets set with a blank value.

Comment: Yes, `action` should be `data-action`.

Comment: A little more info on the issue, i can see in the debugger that the correct forms are being submitted. when i try and remove each item it shows the form ids are different.  In addition data-action is getting the correct action. The issue lies in js("#pageAction").val(action);  It seems that it is never setting the action to pageAction when I try and remove the second item in the list.  It works fine if i try and remove the first item.

Comment: Each form in the page will have this hidden field <input type="hidden" name="pageAction" id="pageAction"> would the fact that the is is the same in each form be causing the issue?

Comment: Please check the updated answer, including `<input type="hidden" name="pageAction" />` and `js` code.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you very much for your time.  One quick question, why is it not so good to use "rel" and what would be the proper place to use rel.  I pretty much understand everything else you did, it was a very clear and well thought out explanation.

Comment: @John, Browsers do not use this attribute in any way. However, search engines can use this attribute to get more information about a link. Also [Read this](http://www.sitepoint.com/rel-not-a-custom-attribute/) and [this too](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-use-various-rel-attributes-learning-microformats/16144/).